# Network architecture for "secure" site

Tags: security, infrastructure

Lately I've been reading about the separation of business logic / admin panel / frontend for users.

The main point writers were pushing towards the reader is that it is best to provide separated architecture for the application. So as I understood it, they want you to have 3 separate "applications":

1. Sever with all business logic and processing
2. Admin panel which is only accessible through the internal network (same as server)
3. Web application which is on separate network and files are replicated to ensure that none of the sensitive data is able to leak.

However, I can't understand whether it is **a must** for a "secure" site or just a precaution in case the backend configured poorly.

Why can't I just use REST and some sort of ACL with protected directories to provide only files and data I need to provide to user?

And what if I want to implement forum on the website? The main "solution" here is to set up a caching server (like YouTube does) and to store temporary data there until it pulled by the server and synchronized with data storage, during this time, some requests will be served by the caching server, what in theory should provide no interruptions in service.

Even though I see a valid point here, for me it seems that the system is over-complicated and there is no point in this type of security measures to be put in place.

Yes, there are some cases of storing and processing of secure data, however, is it really needed?

Answer (score 0):

Making the admin panel internal only so it's separate from the main application can be a good idea and it's something I have done in the past.
The level of security controls you want to apply here depends on what you are trying to protect.

The data need to be classified and a risk assessment performed, which should then drive the type of controls that need to be applied to protect it.